# How to know list of people who gave a Google +1?

Tags: google-plus-1

How to know the list of people who gave a Google Plus One (+1) to the website. The Facebook likes people list are displayed when clicking the like count button, but +1 doesn't displays any user IDs that gave a plus? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to know for your own website, or the list of other people on a general site you don't control?

Comment: What about both of them. The priority is for my own site

Comment: Google Analytics gives you counts, but not details.

Comment: Not an answer to the "my site +1's", but for a Google+ Post, you can click on the "People who +1'd this" link to get the list. (It's the link under the +1 icon that is the current number of +1s.)

Comment: @BusinessInelligence Blogs posts in the Blogger admin pages list +1s for posts that have been liked. Clicking on the +1 link sometimes reveal name of the person who +1-ed it. It appears that the name shows up only if users have opted to display it through some setting.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is possible to determine the identities of the people who gave a Google +1 to a website or URL, whether on your own website or one that you don't control. This wasn't announced until 27 Jun 2012 by Google, a long time after you asked your question! Now **[Google policy seems quite explicit](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/buttons-policy)** (emphasis mine):

> Publishers may not attempt to discover the identity of a Google+ button user
> **unless the user consents to share his or her identity with the Publisher via a
> Google-approved authorization procedure.** This prohibition includes identifying
> users by correlating Google+ button reporting data from Google with Publisher data.
>
> For the avoidance of doubt, **this prohibition includes, but is not limited to, any use of pixels, cookies, or other methods to recognize users’ clicks on a Google+
> button...** Publishers may not direct users to click a Google+ button for purposes
> of misleading users...

I don't know what Google-approved authorization procedure is referred to in the first sentence.

**Enforcement**

I'm not sure how this will be accomplished, other than by web crawlers, but Google sounds like **[they are serious about it](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/buttons-policy)**:

> Google may analyze Publishers' use of a Google+ button to ensure
> Publishers’ compliance with these policies and to facilitate Google’s
> development of Google+ Buttons.

**Google Analytics and Google Webmaster Tools**

Yes, it is true that you can get **[aggregated Google +1 activity data on your own websites from Google Analytics](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1316551&answer=1316556)**. The same is true for Google Webmaster Tools, for your own site or others:

> **Google Webmaster Tools** reports on all +1 interactions for your
> content, regardless of whether the interaction occurs on your own
> domain, or on a search result listing.

However, Google Webmaster Tools also aggregates reports on +1 activity related to your content, so no further detail can be determined.

**Blogger and other social sharing**

As @mvark mentioned, on a Blogger blog, if one is the owner, the admin panel displays how many +1's were given to each post (URL). *Sometimes* the person's identity is disclosed. That seems to be dependent on a variety of factors that include

- Designating that one's Google+ activity on non-Google and Google sites be publicly visible. This setting is in the user permissions page for one's own Google account; and
- *Possibly* if one has some form of Google+ circles relationship with another user who has +1'd that same URL. I have noticed this on non-Blogger websites as well.

### EDIT

Here is a **very** recent page, from 29 October 2012, **[Google Developers, about Social Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSocial)**. It has new information about Google+ tracking as well as Twitter and Facebook likes and un-likes. There is also a **new Google+ private beta program**, that *might* allow you to do what you requested, but I'm not sure who is eligible to participate in it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can get that,Google+ will give you the count but not the list of people with link to there Google+ Profiles.

Answer (score -1):

You can find out with Google Analytics "Network Referrals". It includes "Social User Handle
" and "User Profile URL".