# See complete list of people +1 a page using gplus button

Tags: google-plus

I want get a badge to 10 persons whom +1 [my blog](http://blog.rastasoft.ir). but I can see only 3 of them listed inside of button.

Is there any place to find complete list of these persons?

Answer (score 1):

No. I don't believe it is possible to determine the identities of people who gave a +1 to your blog, or to an individual page (URL) on your blog. I've been trying to find a way to do this for awhile too! As of 29 Oct 2012 (the last time I checked on this) it seems unlikely to be made available by Google. I think the rationale is primarily based on privacy concerns.

For more details, have a look at **[this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/34086/8605)** to a related question. I included links to Google+ and Google +1 button product help pages. They describe what can, and cannot be done at an aggregate level e.g. through Google Webmaster dashboard, versus at an individual identity level.